# Filling A textfield without name with WWW::Mechanize perl

Tags: perl, www-mechanize

I have a textfield like this in HTML

```
<input class="whatever" placeholder="Username">
```

I want to fill it using Mechanize Perl. I can fill it when name attribute is present.I tried

```
use strict;
use warnings;

use WWW::Mechanize;

my $url = 'http://urltoscrap';
my $mech = WWW::Mechanize->new( agent => 'Windows IE 8' );
$mech->get($url);
my $result = $mech->submit_form(
    form_name => 'pf',
    fields    => {
        Username => 'value',
    },
);
print $result->content();
```

It is not working what should I place on place of "Username" to make it work?

Comment: Isn't the name attribute required for form submission?  Is that even valid HTML?  I found this reference at W3Schools:  _"Note: Only form elements with a name attribute will have their values passed when submitting a form."_  Based on that, the `submit` will not be applied to that field.

Answer (score 0):

I'm sure some **JavaScript** code will process this input and make correct HTTP POST/GET. So you just need to find correct request (may be with *Firefox*'s *HTTPFox* / *Firebug* extension) and create same request using `$mech->post(...);`